# Fragment into Bundle

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I have a fragment that I would like to use either as a full screen or as a Dialog content.

I'm trying to pass it this way:

```
companion object {
    val DIALOG_TITLE = "DIALOG_TITLE"
    fun getInstance(title: String, content: Fragment): BaseCustomDialogFragment {
        return BaseCustomDialogFragment().apply {
            arguments?.putString(DIALOG_TITLE, title)
            activity?.fragmentAdd(content)
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this solution won't work. As long the Fragment hasn't been attached, we don't have access to the activity.

Is there any way to achieve the same outcome without triggering the load from the Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. Instead of passing the Fragment, we include Fragment's class and arguments (`Class<T>` and `Bundle`).
Then, we create and add the fragment `onViewCreated()`

Here is the code:

```
class BaseCustomDialogFragment: Fragment() {

companion object {
    val FRAGMENT_CLASS = "FRAGMENT_CLASS"
    val ARGUMENTS_BUNDLE = "ARGUMENTS_BUNDLE"
    fun <T> getInstance(title: String, fragmentClass: Class<T>, bundle: Bundle): BaseCustomDialogFragment {
        return BaseCustomDialogFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle()
            arguments!!.putString(DIALOG_TITLE, title)
            arguments!!.putSerializable(FRAGMENT_CLASS, fragmentClass)
            arguments!!.putBundle(ARGUMENTS_BUNDLE, bundle)
        }
    }
}

private lateinit var className: Class<*>
private lateinit var bundle: Bundle

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    (arguments?.getSerializable(FRAGMENT_CLASS) as? Class<*>)?.let { className = it }
    arguments?.getBundle(ARGUMENTS_BUNDLE)?.let { bundle = it }

    // Inflate View.
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom_dialog, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setContentUp()
}

private fun setContentUp(){
    val fragment = createFragment(className, bundle)

    activity?.supportFragmentManager
            ?.beginTransaction()
            ?.add(R.id.fragment_dialog_placeholder, fragment)
            ?.disallowAddToBackStack()
            ?.commit()
}

private fun <T> createFragment(fragmentClass: Class<T>, arguments: Bundle): Fragment {
    val fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance() as Fragment
    fragment.arguments = arguments
    return fragment
}
```

I hope it helps to somebody.